# Change int value from another class, Update JPanel

Tags: java, swing

When I press a specific key, I want to update an `int` value in another class and repaint a `JPanel` based on this updated `int`.

Here is my code for the class with the `key_event`:

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                dP.status = 1;
                w.x = w.x; //pos.xC(pos.maxSize(frame));
                w.y = w.Y(w.y, -w.val);
                if ( w.y < 0) {
                    w.y = 0; 
                }
                frame.validate();
                dP.repaint(); 
                System.out.println("w.y: "+w.y); 
            }
});
```

Here is my class with the `int` supposed to be updated:

```
public class Objects {

public int x = 10;
public int y = 10;  
public int height = 10; 
public int width = 10; 

public int val = 5;

public void dW(Graphics stift){

    stift.setColor(Color.RED);
    stift.fillRect(x, y, width, height);    
}
}
```

And here is my `JPanel` class:

```
public class DisplayPanel extends JPanel {

public Objects w = new Objects();

public int status = 0; 

public  void setUp(){
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics stift){
        super.paintComponent(stift);

        if (status == 0){
            stift.setColor(Color.RED);
            stift.drawLine(200, 200, 400, 200);
            stift.drawLine(200, 400, 300, 500);

            stift.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            stift.drawLine(200, 200, 2000, 200);
            stift.fillRect(w.x, w.y, w.width, w.height);    
        }

        while (status == 1){
            w.dW(stift); 
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

While pressing the key for the first time, the JPanel is updated, the values for w.x and w.y wont update, they remain exact 10. How can I change this?

(PS: I know that it would be better to implement a switch case break statement for the key_events).

Comment: You initialize w right at the beginning of your JPanel class. I'm just guessing now but it looks like the w object in your listener (which appears to be set somewhere outset the frame?) is a different one. They need to work on the same reference. If you define "public Object w" twice that's already wrong.

Comment: @Zi1mann Show your codes for Objects.X() and Objects.Y(). What did you do in those accessor methods?